# Why is my Windows 10 PC only getting 1/3rd of the speed my MacBook Pro is getting on the same exact network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I pay for 600Mbps upload/download, and that's more or less what I get through Wi-Fi on my MacBook Pro. I've just bought an HP Omen and installed Windows 10, and I can't get it to even reach 200Mbps.

I thought it might be an issue with the signal coming from my ISP’s router, so I installed a router that works with Wi-Fi 6. As soon as I connected to it on my PC I got a notification literally congratulating me for being connected to a Wi-Fi 6 router, that I would get high speeds and reliability… And it said: “Enjoy!” Well, I would “enjoy” but for some reason Windows 10 keeps capping my speed at less than 200Mbps, effectively giving me around 150Mbps upload/download to work with. Why would this be happening?

The Wi-Fi card in my HP Omen is Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz

I’ve tried the only supposed solution I could find, which was to set the “Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level” to “disabled,” and nothing happened. It was originally set to “normal,” so I've since put it back the way it was.

Comment: Try to install the [Intel driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/189347/Intel-Wi-Fi-6-AX200-Gig-).

Comment: Hi @harrymc, and thanks for the recommendation! I've now done so and it seems to be a bit better: I'm getting up to 200Mbps now. But no more than that.